# HDMI output detected but no signal under Kubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I am using Kubuntu 20.04. I have dual boot and used an HDMI TV to extend the screen, worked perfect so far. However, when I switch to Linux, the HDMI display does not receive signal at all (Displays NO SIGNAL message).

The output of my xrandr is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
HDMI-1-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x720      60.00 +  59.94    50.00  
   1920x1080     59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

The curious thing is that it gets detected but returns no output:

[image]

Comment: Using `$ xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --mode 1280x720
` failed returning `xrandr: Configure crtc 4 `

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem and the solution. My laptop has an AMD & NVIDIA GPU.

The physical connector is managed by AMD, and NVIDIA controls the output. To check whether this is your problem run: `glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"`

My output was similar to this:

[image]

Then, I edited my xorg.conf files to fix the issue and designate NVIDIA as primary driver:

First, remember to make backups of your delicate files:

```
sudo cp -p /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf

sudo cp -p /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf.backup
```

Then, edit your files. Open 10-nvidia.conf and `Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"`  before the EndSection line so it looks like this:

[image]

Next, open the file 10-amdgpu.config and replace the line ``` Driver "amdgpu"``Driver "modesetting" ```

Save everything, reboot yur system and the outputs should work fine now!

Test which one is your default HMMI driver:

`glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"`

[image]

Based on: https://9to5linux.com/how-to-connect-your-laptop-to-an-external-monitor-on-linux-fix-for-hdmi-no-signal-issue